# How can Bada Application be registered, so that Widget can launch it?

Tags: bada

I have a Bada application. How can it be launched by Widget ? The application cannot be listed out via `bondi.applauncher.getInstalledApplications`

How can it be registered so that Widget can launch it ?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no solution for this.
Hopefully we see more in the next version.